# Linux speak english,hpux italian,why?

Tags: bash, locale, slackware, i18n

I want my system speak italian as possible 
on hpux,using bash i see

```
help eval
eval: eval [arg ...]
    Esegue argomenti come un comando di shell.

    Combina gli ARGOMENTI dentro una singola stringa usando il risultato
    come input per la shell ed esegue i comandi risultanti.

    Stato di uscita:
    Restituisce lo stato di uscita del comando o successo se il comando è nullo.
```

Using posix shell

```
$ help ls
Non vi sono informazioni a proposito di ls
```

Is 100% italian as i want

On linux,using the same locale(it_IT.utf8) of hpux
i see

```
help eval
eval: eval [arg ...]
    Execute arguments as a shell command.

    Combine ARGs into a single string, use the result as input to the shell,
    and execute the resulting commands.

    Exit Status:
    Returns exit status of command or success if command is null.
```

The translation of hpux is better than linux or there are some other things to do?

Comment: Could you specify the distribution please?

Comment: Slackware linux 14.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need the translation files installed.  On an Ubuntu system, Italian support is added by running:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install language-pack-it-base language-pack-it manpages-it
```

I think on Red Hat and Fedora, it's something like

```
yum groupinstall italian-support
```

You will also need to use one of the supported locale names, which you can get by running `locale -a`, and set `LANGUAGE` accordingly (I'm not sure if `LANGUAGE` is required on HP-UX).

On my system:

```
$ LC_ALL=it_IT.UTF-8 LANG=it_IT.UTF-8 LANGUAGE=it_IT
$ help eval
eval: eval [arg ...]
Esegue argomenti come un comando di shell.
...
```

Comment: in debian "sudo apt-get install manpages-it"...it varies a little depending on the distribution, which was not specified. You can also set the locale with "dpkg-reconfigure locales" as "locale -a" is just for consulting it.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Note that in this case, the help comes from bash's inbuilt help, so you'll also need whatever provides `LC_MESSAGES/bash.mo`.  On Ubuntu, that's `language-pack-it-base`.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Will have to test it out maybe tomorrow, I hate to have things in IT operating in my mother tongue.

Comment: I've down voted cause the question is tagged with the `slackware` tag. So I think this answer useless.

Comment: @slacksmart That was added after I answered. Let's see what the command would be on Slackware...

Comment: From a quick look, and per http://docs.slackware.com/slackware:localization, I don't think Slackware provides non-English man pages.  But it looks like the `bash` package (http://mirrors.slackware.com/slackware/slackware-14.1/slackware/a/) includes all the locale files, so this specific problem should be solved by setting `LC_*`, `LANG`, and/or `LANGUAGE` appropriately, per my answer.